# Meaning of a** operator

Tags: c

Can you tell me the meaning of `a**=b;` in C. Also please define the `**` operator;

Comment: While not a C operator, in some languages such as Python and Ruby ** is the power operator (e.g. x**y returns x to the power of y)

Comment: Please post a code sample where that "operator" appears.

Answer (score 16):

There is no such operator (`**=`) in C. It results in [syntax error](http://ideone.com/yLuP8).

---

There "is" `**` in C though, which is always tokenized as `*` followed by a `*`, e.g.

```
int a;
int* b;
int** d;

int c = a**b;  // c = (a) * (*b)
int e =** d;   // e = *(*d)
```

Your code `a**=b` is tokenized as `a` `*` `*=` `b`, which is syntax error.

Comment: @Azz: `b` is a pointer to an int, and the unary `*` *dereferences* the pointer to give back an `int`. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computing)#C_pointers

Comment: @Azz: if be is a pointer, then `*b` is the value pointed by the pointer; this is called dereferencing.

Comment: Thanks mate, I've never touched C but it just intrigued me.

Comment: @azz: (Off topic) [C# has this too (with the same syntax)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcy5wf0h.aspx), but that is unsafe code. :)

Answer (score 2):

That type ( **)  operator not aviable in c . If you use then it will give compile time error.

Comment: Wrong... that's two pointer dereference operators as stated in another answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is no `**=` operator in C. In C `**` is used for pointer to a pointer.

example: `int **a` refers to a pointer to an integer pointer. here `a` stores address of an integer pointer.